# How to store a list of validators from a generic object. C#

Tags: c#, validation, user-input

I'm developing a input validation library for my APIs.

```
interface IValidation<T>{
    List<string> Errors(); 
    bool Valid(T input);
}

class GuidValidator: IValidation<Guid> {
    bool Valid(Guid input){ ... }
}

class StringLengthValidator: IValidation<String> {
    bool Valid(String input){ ... }
}
```

and am trying to validate

```
class MyInputToValidate {
    public Guid Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string Description {get;set;}
}
```

from the controller

```
class MyController { 
    public ActionResult Post([FromBody] MyInputToValidate body){
        ValidatorCollection validators = new ValidatorCollection<MyInputToValidate>();

        validators.AddValidator(i => i.Id, new GuidValidator());
        validators.AddValidator(i => i.Name, new LengthValidator());
        validators.AddValidator(i => i.Description, new LengthValidator());

        bool valid = validators.Validate(body);

        //...
    }
}
```

But I'm having difficulty saving the validators to a dictionary for later use.

```
interface IValidatorCollection<T> {
     void AddValidator<TProperty>(
        Expression<Func<T, TProperty>> property,
        IValidator<TProperty> validator
    );

    bool Validate(T value);
}

class ValidatorCollection: IValidatorCollection<T> {
    private IDictionary<string, IValidator<object>> _validators = new Dictionary<string, IValidator<object>>();

    public void AddValidator<TProperty>(Expression<Func<T, TProperty>> property, IValidator<TProperty> validator)
    {
        _validators.Add(property.Name, validator);
    }

    public bool Validate(T value)
    {
        foreach(var val in _validators){
            bool valid = val.Value.Valid(value);
        }

        //...
    }
}
```

I receive the error `IValidator<TProperty> is not assignable to to IValidator<object>` for the line `_validators.Add(property.Name, validator);`.  I've tried typecasting `(IValidator<object>validator)`, but I receive the runtime error `Unable to cast object GuidValidator to type IValidator<object>`.  How can I store a list of validators for the properties of a generic object?

Comment: Looking at your code, I do believe you want a colleciton of types <IValidation<T>> I would go with that approach to fix your problem.

Comment: The validators are for `TProperty`.  IE, I can't attached a `String` validator directly to the `MyInputToValidate` object.